# Disable Office for Mac 2011 First Use Registration

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

I'm setting up some macbooks for use in a cart for a school. Students would share the computers. When users first run any office applications, they get a window saying that they need to put in their first name (last name/company name optional) in order to continue.

Is there any way to disable or bypass this and have it go straight to word/excel/powerpoint? I've tried copying some microsoft office plist files from the preferences folder on an account where I've already registered to the english.lproj file in user templates but that did not work. I've also tried copying over the Microsoft folder from application support into the english.lproj folder with no luck.

Any advice?

Comment: I think I solved my own question. This page helps a lot:

http://www.officeformachelp.com/office/administration/mcx/

I had to also move along some additional preference files into the user template english.lproj folder. The additional files were:

com.microsoft.autoupdate2
com.microsoft.error_reporting
com.microsoft.office

Comment: Suggest you expand your answer into something a little clearer for the uninitiated reader, clean up the formatting, and then put it in the Answer section below. (You can answer your own questions.)